# How to loop through Json file using Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to print all the premier league fixtures this season through a JSON file I downloaded, using python. Here is the link to the Json file I am using - [Json File](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendatajson/football.json/master/2016-17/en.1.json)

I have managed to print the fixtures of the first matchday using a while loop. I want the date, home team, "vs", away team. I think I need to use an outer loop to loop through the other matchdays but I need help on this.

```
import json
with open('en.1.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    matchday = data['rounds'][0]['matches']
    i = 0
    while i < len(matchday):
        home = matchday[i]['team1']
        away = matchday[i]['team2']
        date =  matchday[i]['date']
        print date, home['name'], "vs", away['name']
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: you have indentation pb in your while loop

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple and intuitive solution to the problem you are facing:

```
with open(premierleaguedatafile) as data_file:
    # loads the entire dataset into a dictionary
    data = json.load(data_file) 

# get the list of all the rounds of fixtures
rounds = data['rounds']

# iterate over each round
for matchday in rounds:
    # store the list of matches played on this matchday
    matches = matchday['matches'] 

    # iterate over the matches to get individual match details
    for match in matches:
        match_date = match['date']
        home_team = match['team1']['name']
        away_team = match['team2']['name']
        print('{} {} vs {}'.format(match_date, home_team, away_team))
```

Comment: There's no reason to hold the file open after the data is loaded - you should outdent "# get the list..." and all following lines.